# Inner Join en Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Estoy tratando de mostrar el nombre de un proveedor, así como también el nombre de la huerta en lugar de su id de la tabla entradas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que no se como es la sintaxis en `Codeigniter` para traer y mostrar esos datos.

Modelo:

```
public function getEntradas(){
     $this->db->join('proveedor', 'proveedor.id = entrada.PROVEEDOR');
     $result = $this->db->get('entrada');
     return $result->result();
}
```

Controlador:

```
$data = array(
    'entradas' => $this->Modelfruta->getEntradas()
);
$this->load->view('content/head');
$this->load->view('content/aside');
$this->load->view('pages/proceso/fruta/viewfruta',$data);
$this->load->view('content/footer');
$this->load->view('content/scrips/proceso/srcontrols');
```

Vista:

```
<?php if(!empty($entradas)): ?>
  <?php foreach($entradas as $entradas): ?>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
     <td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1"><?php echo $entradas->id; ?></td>
     <td><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/profile.png" class="avatar" alt="Avatar"><span style="margin-left:10px;"></span><?php echo $entradas->PROVEEDOR; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $entradas->peso; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $entradas->cajas; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $entradas->hora; ?></td>
     <td><a href="" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-remove">No impreso</a></td>
     <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Ingresado</button></td>
     <td><a href="" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Modificar</a>
         <a href="" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-remove">Eliminar</a>    
     </td>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Columnas de mi tabla:

```
<thead>
   <tr role="row">
   <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-buttons" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 100px;" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Name: activate to sort column descending">#</th>
  <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-buttons" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 200px;" aria-label="Position: activate to sort column ascending">Proveedor</th>
  <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-buttons" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 100px;" aria-label="Office: activate to sort column ascending">Peso</th>
  <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-buttons" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 100px;" aria-label="Age: activate to sort column ascending">Cajas</th>
  <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-buttons" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 100px;" aria-label="Start date: activate to sort column ascending">Hora</th>
  <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-buttons" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 100px;" aria-label="Start date: activate to sort column ascending">Impresion</th>
 <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-buttons" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 100px;" aria-label="Start date: activate to sort column ascending">Etapa procesada</th>
 <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-buttons" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 100px;" aria-label="Salary: activate to sort column ascending">Herramientas</th></tr>
</thead>
```

¿Como puedo mostrar el nombre?
como lo tengo actualmente, no me muestra nada.

Comment: es una relación muchos a muchos verdad? una tabla llamada: proveedor, huertas y entradas?

Comment: si, así es son 3 tablas _entradas_ la que junta la información de ambas

Comment: añade por fas a tu pregunta la estructura de tus tablas, es decir sus columnas

Comment: Listo ya he añadido mis columnas

Comment: Con la respuesta que te agregue es más que suficiente para que muestres tu información :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realizar un `INNER JOIN` en `Codeigniter` lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma:

Controlador:

```
public function getEntradas()
{
    $data['entradas'] = $this->Data_model->getEntradas();
    $this->load->view('admin/nombre', $data);
}
```

Modelo:

```
public function getEntradas()
{
    $this->db->select('a.*,d.*');
    $this->db->from('entradas a');
    $this->db->join('proveedor d', 'a.proveedor = d.id');

    $aResult = $this->db->get();

    if(!$aResult->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return $aResult->result_array();
}
```

Vista:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>campo 1</th>
    <th>campo 2</th>
    <th>campo 3</th>
  </tr>
  <?php foreach($entradas as $entrada){ ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $entrada['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $entrada['campo1']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $entrada['campo2']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $entrada['campo3']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <? } ?>
</table>
```

De esta forma imprimes toda la información que traes de tu consulta, recorriendo el arreglo y mostrándolo por el nombre de su campo. supuse lo que tenias ya que no muestras las tablas de tu base de datos como para decirte con exactitud como hacerlo, pero esto es mas que suficiente y es muy sencillo.

Comment: me funciono muy bien, salvo porque si te das cuenta accedo a los elemento de modificar y eliminar por el id de entrada, pero me da el id de proveedor. ¿como puedo hacer la diferencia al momento de mostrar?

Comment: Estas accediendo por medio del id, y estas mostrando los demas campos, pues unicamenten puedes guardar el campo id al momento de eliminar, o utilizar $entrada['id'] para tus eliminaciones.

Si resolviste tu problema respecto a tu pregunta puedes marcar la respuesta como buena, las demas dudas se te pueden resolver por aqui o si es algo mas complejo por medio de otra pregunta. Ya que no se conoce la estructura de tu base de datos, y tampoco sabemos como estas haciendo los métodos de modificar y eliminar.

Comment: Y para acceder al id del proveedor basta con hacer un select del id del proveedor as idproveedor y ya con ese nombre lo mandas a llamar.