# Problema con Vista en CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mvc

Hola a todos tengo un problema que no me refleja en una vista los datos de otra tabla asociada, si me muestra el ID con la referencia de la columna pero yo quiero que me de los nombres, aca esta el modelo:
Es un CRUD:
La vista tiene agregar, editar y eliminar, cuando edito si aparecen los datos, pero cuando los visualizo unicamente aparecen los ids:

```
function update_asignacion($id,$params){
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    return $this->db->update('asignacion',$params);
}
```

El index:

```
function index(){
    $data['asignacion'] = $this->Asignacion_model->get_all_asignacion();
    $data['_view'] = 'asignacion/index';
    $this->load->view('layouts/main',$data);
}
```

el controlador de la vista editar:

```
function edit($id){   
    // check if the asignacion exists before trying to edit it
    $data['asignacion'] = $this->Asignacion_model->get_asignacion($id);

    if(isset($data['asignacion']['id'])){
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('alumno_id','Alumno Id','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('curso_id','Curso Id','required');

        if($this->form_validation->run())     {   
            $params = array(
                'alumno_id' => $this->input->post('alumno_id'),
                'curso_id' => $this->input->post('curso_id'),
            );

            $this->Asignacion_model->update_asignacion($id,$params);            
            redirect('asignacion/index');
        } else {
            $this->load->model('Alumno_model');
            $data['all_alumnos'] = $this->Alumno_model->get_all_alumnos();

            $this->load->model('Curso_model');
            $data['all_cursos'] = $this->Curso_model->get_all_cursos();

            $data['_view'] = 'asignacion/edit';
            $this->load->view('layouts/main',$data);
        }
    }else{
        show_error('The asignacion you are trying to edit does not exist.');
    }
}
```

y la vista (esta es la vista del index):

```
<?php foreach($asignacion as $a){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $a['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $a['alumno_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $a['curso_id']; ?></td>
        <td>
            <a href="<?php echo site_url('asignacion/edit/'.$a['id']); ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span> Edit</a> 
            <a href="<?php echo site_url('asignacion/remove/'.$a['id']); ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span> Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

esta es la vista de Editar:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="alumno_id" class="form-control">
        <option value="">select alumno</option>
        <?php foreach($all_alumnos as $alumno){
            $selected = ($alumno['id'] == $asignacion['alumno_id']) ? ' selected="selected"' : "";
            echo '<option value="'.$alumno['id'].'" '.$selected.'>'.$alumno['nombre'].'</option>';
        } ?>
    </select>
    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('alumno_id');?></span>
</div>
```

Pero ya intente colocarlo de la misma manera en el index y me error. Les agradeceria su ayuda por favor. Saludos

Capturas

[image: Aca se Agregar los datos]

[image: Aca es donde se listan pero solo aparecen los id]

Comment: Que error te da?

Comment: No me da los nombres de los campos de las tablas unicamente los id

Comment: colocare unas capturas para que de a entender

Comment: colocare unas capturas para que de a entender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El hecho de que las `tablas` estén relacionadas no quiere decir que sus atributos van a venir por si solos al mandar a llamar a su `id`. Puedes traer esos datos de la siguiente manera en tu `Modelo` con la sintaxis de `Codeigniter`.

```
public function obtenerDatos(){
    $this->db->select('t.*,a.*,c.*');
    $this->db->from('tabla t');
    $this->db->join('alumno a', 't.alumno_id = a.id');
    $this->db->join('curso c', 't.curso_id = c.id');

    $aResult = $this->db->get();
    if(!$aResult->num_rows() == 1){
        return false;
    }

    return $aResult->result_array();
}
```

Básicamente estas trayendo todos los datos de la primera tabla, de la tabla `alumno` y de la tabla `curso` y los estas retornando en un arreglo al controlador donde ya debes ver que datos son los que te regresa para posteriormente mandarlos a la vista, en este caso hice uso de `join` para sacar los datos de las relaciones tomando como parámetro que el `alumno_id` sea igual al `id` de la tabla alumno y de igual forma para el curso.

Si quieres ver como se hace el uso en el `Modelo`,`Vista` y `Controlador` te invito a que visites la referencia, es una pregunta que conteste donde muestro todo de la forma mas sencilla posible y te digo como hacer la petición del `controlador` al `modelo`, recibir respuesta y esa respuesta enviarla a la `vista`.

Referencia: [Inner Join en Codeigniter](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/154792/inner-join-en-codeigniter/)

Comment: Gracias amigo de esa manera lo hice, gracias por tu respuesta!

Comment: Excelente me da gusto que te sirviera, mucha suerte!

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es en la consulta ya que traes toda la información de la tabla en la cual la información se ve de la siguiente manera:

```
|----|-----------|----------|
| id | alumno_id | curso_id |
|----|-----------|----------|
|  1 |    1      |     1    |
|----|-----------|----------|
```

Que esten relacionadas no quiere decir que por defecto te va a traer la información de la otra tabla. Lo que debes de hacer es una consulta relacionando los datos de las tablas. Tu función `get_all_asignacion` del modelo quedaría asi:

```
$queryBD = "SELECT a.id, h.nombre as alumno, c.nombre as curso "
           . "FROM asignacion a, alumno h, curso c "
           . "WHERE h.id_alumno = a.id_alumno AND c.id_curso = a.id_curso ";
$query = $this->db->query($queryBD);
return $query;
```

Asumiendo que los nombres de tus tablas son `asignacion`, `alumno` y `curso`.